# Dojo/Dijit writing own widget, mixin issues

Tags: widget, dojo, template-mixins

Just a minor problem, but it drives me nuts. I want to write my own widget using TabContainers. Now it seems, that the mixin-Classes can't call the TabContainer modules and start them. I tried a lots of stuff with different widgets, and it seems that there is just an issue with the TabContainer. Looking at the Doc I wasn't able to figure out whether it is a bug within Dojo or within my code. Nonetheless, this works

```
<script type="text/template" id="editMultilanguageDialog-form-template">
  <form data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Form" data-dojo-attach-point="form">
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCut', showLabel: false" type="button">cut</button>
  </form>
</script>
```

...but this doesn't!

```
<script type="text/template" id="editMultilanguageDialog-form-template">
  <form data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Form" data-dojo-attach-point="form">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="My first tab" data-dojo-props="selected:true">
            Lorem ipsum and all around...
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="My second tab">
            Lorem ipsum and all around - second...
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="My last tab" data-dojo-props="closable:true">
            Lorem ipsum and all around - last...
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</script>
```

The code called within the dialog.js looks like this:

```
 define([ "modules/waitingDialog/dialog", "util/debugger", "stores/userStore",
    "util/storeCache", "dojo/Evented", "dijit/Dialog", "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/_Widget", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin", "dojo/dom", "dojo/_base/Deferred",
    "modules/editMultilanguageDialog/controller", "stores/facultyStore",
    "stores/degreeStore", "stores/beginOfStudyStore" ], function(wait,
    debug, userStore, storeCache, Evented, Dialog, lang, declare, widget,
    templatedMixin, widgetsInTemplateMixin, dom, Deferred,
    editMultilanguageController, facultyStore, degreeStore,
    beginOfStudyStore) {
return declare("editMultilanguageDialog", [ Dialog, Evented ], {

    attributeMap : lang.delegate(widget.prototype.attributeMap, {
        message : {
            node : "messageNode",
            type : "innerHTML"
        }
    }),

    constructor : function(/* Object */kwArgs) {
        debug.log("constructor called",
                "editMultilanguageDialog.constructor()", 1);
        lang.mixin(this, kwArgs);

        var controller = new editMultilanguageController(kwArgs);
        this.controller = controller;

        var dialogTemplate = dom.byId("dialog-template").textContent;
        var formTemplate = dom
                .byId("editMultilanguageDialog-form-template").textContent;
        var template = lang.replace(dialogTemplate, {
            form : formTemplate
        });

        var contentWidget = new (declare([ widget, templatedMixin,
                widgetsInTemplateMixin ], {
            templateString : template,
            widgetsInTemplate : true
        }));

        var content = this.content = contentWidget;

        this.form = content.form;

        contentWidget.startup();
    }, [...]
```

This problem is driving me nuts. Thought anyone may have experienced same issues by writing custom widgets. Thx in advance!

Comment: Saying something "doesn't work" is pretty vague, could you elaborate? Does it throw an error? render? render incorrectly/empty? Providing a jsfiddle would make it even easier for people to help you.

Comment: what dojo version are you using ? a working & not working example on jsfiddle would help